# Delete all but the 50 newest rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table with news stories and Unix timestamps. I'd like to only keep the 50 newest stories. How would I write an SQL statement to delete any amount of older stories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using two queries since MySQL5 doesn't yet support LIMIT's in subqueries

```
SELECT unixTime FROM entries ORDER BY unixTime DESC LIMIT 49, 1;
DELETE FROM entries WHERE unixTime < $sqlResult;
```

Answer (score 8):

Blockquote

```
delete from table where id not in (
    select id from table 
    order by id desc 
    limit 50
)
```

You select the ids of the data you don't want to delete, and the you delete everything NOT IN these value...

Comment: This assumes you have sequential ID's, which is usually a fair assumption. If you don't though, you'll need to make use of a timestamp or some other sequential field in your DB to do this

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, just get the error: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Surely the subquery should be "select id from table", not "select * from table" ?

Comment: @Gilean you should tune this query and see what kind of commands your mysql version supports. This was only an input for your question...

Comment: Looks like LIMIT isn't supported in subqueries in MySQL 5

Comment: Shouldn't order by be on the timestamp field?

Answer (score 3):

Well, it sort of looks like you can't do it in one query - someone correct me if I'm wrong.  The only way I've ever been able to do this sort of thing is to first figure out the number of rows in the table. For Example:

```
select count(*) from table;
```

then using the result do

```
delete from table order by timestamp limit result - 50;
```

You have to do it this way for two reasons -

1. MySQL 5 doesn't support limit in subqueries for delete
2. MySQL 5 doesn't allow you to select in a subquery from the same table you are deleting from.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a lot of rows, it might be better to put the 50 rows in a temporary table
then use **TRUNCATE TABLE** to empty the table out.  Then put the 50 rows back in.

Comment: Truncate resets the auto increment counter - so if your IDs are on auto-increment you would need to modify the next value of auto-increment after truncating the table so that the next ID comes after the highest value of the data you kept.

Answer (score 0):

I've just done it like this:

`` DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `datetime` < (SELECT `datetime` FROM `table` ORDER BY `datetime` DESC LIMIT 49,1); ``

Where `table` is the table, `datetime` is a datetime field.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this query selects the rows you want to keep:

```
SELECT timestampcol FROM table ORDER BY timestampcol DESC LIMIT 49,1;
```

Then you could use a subquery like so:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE timestampcol < ( SELECT timestampcol FROM table ORDER BY timestampcol DSEC LIMIT 49,1 )
```

Of course, make sure you have a backup before doing anything as potentially destructive. Note that compared to the other approaches mentioned, which use `IN`, this one will avoid doing 50 integer comparisons for every row to be deleted, making it (potentially) 50 times faster - assuming I got my SQL right.

Comment: This doesn't work (#1093 - You can't specify target table 'entries' for update in FROM clause). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/sql-delete-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score -2):

Maybe not the most efficient, but this should work:

```
DELETE FROM _table_ 
WHERE _date_ NOT IN (SELECT _date_ FROM _table_ ORDER BY _date_ DESC LIMIT 50)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, MYSQL5 doesn't support LIMIT in subqueries: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery